# JSON Decode (PHP)

Tags: php, json, decode

how can I Select the value of "success" from that json?:

```
{
"response": {
    "success": true,
    "groups": [
        {
            "gid": "3229727"
        },
        {
            "gid": "4408371"
        }
    ]

}
}
```

Thats my current code:

```
$result = json_decode ($json);
$success = $result['response'][0]['success'];
    echo $success;
```

Thank you.
Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here You go... with a [Quick-Test Here](https://eval.in/676673):

```
    <?php

        $strJson    = '{
            "response": {
                "success": true,
                "groups": [
                        {
                            "gid": "3229727"
                        },
                        {
                            "gid": "4408371"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }';


        $data       = json_decode($strJson);
        $success    = $data->response->success;
        $groups     = $data->response->groups;

        var_dump($data->response->success); //<== YIELDS::      boolean true
        var_dump($groups[0]->gid);          //<== YIELDS::      string '3229727' (length=7)
        var_dump($groups[1]->gid);          //<== YIELDS::      string '4408371' (length=7)
```

> **UPDATE::** ***Handling the value of `success` within a Conditional Block.***

```
    <?php

        $data       = json_decode($strJson);
        $success    = $data->response->success;
        $groups     = $data->response->groups;

        if($success){
             echo "success";
             // EXECUTE SOME CODE FOR A SUCCESS SCENARIO...
        }else{
             echo "failure";
             // EXECUTE SOME CODE FOR A FAILURE SCENARIO...
        }
```

Comment: Thank you ver much, how can i add a if query like if($success == true){ echo "success"; } ?

Comment: Perfect, Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

You are almost near to solution. place "**true**" as second argument for `json_decode()`.

Eg:

```
$result = json_decode ($json, true);
$result['response']['success'];`  -> to get the value of success.
```